# Windows Context menu shell icon

Tags: windows, registry, windows-explorer

I have created a new Windows shell context menu item using registry and keys

```
HKLM\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\appname
HKLM\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\appname\command
```

now I want to add an icon to this command. How I do that?

Comment: Are you implementing IContextMenu ?

Comment: Nope, just adding an entry into "HKCR\.myextension\shell" into registry

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Windows 7 added support for icons (and submenus) for static (registry) verbs, add a REG_SZ value named "Icon" under HKCR\%ProgID%\shell\%verb%

On <= Vista you need a [shell extension that implements IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881(v=VS.85).aspx), see [this blog entry](http://www.nanoant.com/programming/themed-menus-icons-a-complete-vista-xp-solution) for information about which icon/bitmap formats you can use...

Comment: Windows 8 is consistent with the Windows 7 icon support