# How to make icon appear next to window custom shell entry?

Tags: windows, shell, registry

Here is what I did to add a custom shell entry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Shows "Open ConsoleZ Here" when right clicking a directory
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ConsoleZ]
@="Open ConsoleZ Here"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe"

; Shows "Open ConsoleZ Here" when right clicking a file
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ConsoleZ]
@="Open ConsoleZ Here"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe"

; Shows "Open ConsoleZ Here" when right clicking desktop or background
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ConsoleZ]
@="Open ConsoleZ Here"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe"
```

How should I modify this to make an icon appear next to my custom shell entry?

[image]

I have tried the suggestions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681032/set-icon-for-custom-right-click-context-menu-item-for-all-desktop-shortcuts-win) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093516/windows-context-menu-shell-icon) with no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set icon for custom right-click context menu item for all desktop shortcuts (windows explorer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681032/set-icon-for-custom-right-click-context-menu-item-for-all-desktop-shortcuts-win)

Answer (score 3):

I tried the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090678/288341) again and it worked.  For prosperity:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Shows "Open ConsoleZ Here" when right clicking a directory
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ConsoleZ]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ConsoleZ]
@="Open ConsoleZ Here"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe"
"Position"="Top"
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe -d \"%V\""

; Shows "Open ConsoleZ Here" when right clicking a file that is not executable
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ConsoleZ]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ConsoleZ]
@="Open ConsoleZ Here"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe"
"Position"="Top"
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe -d \"%W\""

; Shows "Open ConsoleZ Here" when right clicking desktop or background
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ConsoleZ]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ConsoleZ]
@="Open ConsoleZ Here"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe"
"Position"="Top"
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\ConsoleZ\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ConsoleZ\\Console.exe"
```